# Scipy Differential Evolution - Extraction of percentage of invalid population energies (via callback?)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, statistics, differential-evolution

I am currently working on an optimization problem and would like to extract the information of the **fraction of invalid population energies** from the package during **each iteration step** of the optimization.

Currently I am using a callback to get the best solution and the convergence:

```
    def __call__(self, xk: NDArray[float64], convergence: float) -> bool:
```

Is it possible to get the population energies via the callback?

I'm working with scipy 1.12.0 in python 3.11.2.

I already altered the dependency (scipy differential evolution) to print the fraction, but this is not a solution I would like to keep long term).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you call `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(..., callback=lambda intermediate_result: print(intermediate_result))` you'll get your callback called after every iteration. Can you get the invalid population energies from the intermediate `OptimizeResult` that's passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

As os scipy 1.12.0 callbacks can contain `intermediate_result: OptimizeResult`, which is a dict structure, that can contain different parameters, depending on the scipy optimization it is returned from.

The contents of the `OptimizeResult` weren't clear from scipys documentation.

For the differential_evolution these contain additionally to the parameters named in the documentation: `population`, `population_energies`, `constr`, `constr_violation` and `convergence`.

I needed to replace `xk` and `convergence` in the callback with `intermediate_result: OptimizeResult`. The population_energies, x and the convergence can then be accessed from there.

```
def __call__(self, intermediate_result: OptimizeResult) -> bool:
```

The fraction of invalid population energies can be calculated by:

```
sum(np.isinf(intermediate_result.population_energies))/len(intermediate_result.population_energies)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're still missing code in both your question and answer. As it is right now, your post is only helpful to you since you're the only one who has the code. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question and then the corrected code with your answer.

Comment: I have provided additional information.